# How to add unique images to various number of custom markers on google map via json in android

Tags: android, json, image, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm a beginner in Android.

I have a google map in my application. **I need to show some markers on of it and that markers' datas comes from a JSON. Images that i want to use in markers are not static, stored in server and my JSON also contains image URL.**

What is the most proper way to implement this task.

I used **asynctask** class in order to download images, if i've just one marker in that JSON that works well however if JSON contains more than one element, loop tries to invoke more than one asynctask. Even i don't see any exception in the end i can't see any marker on my map.

This is my handler:

```
        private final Handler handler = new Handler() {

            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                String response = msg.getData().getString("message");
                try {

                    JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(response);
                    unitObjectArray = new Unit[jArr.length()];

                    for (int i = 0; i < jArr.length(); i++) {
                        Unit units = new Unit();
                        JSONObject jsnparse = jArr.getJSONObject(i);
                        units.setdLatitude(jsnparse.getString("lat"));
                        units.setdLongitude(jsnparse.getString("lon"));     
                        units.setId(jsnparse.getInt("id"));
                        units.setUrl("http://.../layout/img/avatar/"+jsnparse.getInt("id")+".png");
                        dlati = Double.parseDouble(units.getdLatitude());
                        dlongi = Double.parseDouble(units.getdLongitude());
                        units.setDlati(dlati);
                        units.setDlongi(dlongi);
                        unitObjectArray[i] = units;

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                if ((null != response)) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < unitObjectArray.length; i++) {
 //************************if unitObjectArray.length equals to one that works*************
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getBaseContext(),
                                "Server Response: "
                                        + unitObjectArray[i].getDlati()
                                        + unitObjectArray[i].getDlongi(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        markerLatLng = new LatLng(unitObjectArray[i]
                                .getDlati(), unitObjectArray[i].getDlongi());
                        setUpMap(i);
                    }

                } else {
                    // ALERT MESSAGE
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Not Got Response From Server.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        };
```

This is setUpMap method:

```
private void setUpMap(int i) {
   mMap = ((SupportMapFragment)     getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

         marker = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
            .inflate(R.layout.custom_marker_layout, null);

            imageFromUrl= (ImageView)marker.findViewById(R.id.imageFromUrl);

            new DownloadImageFromUrl().execute(unitObjectArray[i].getUrl());

            customMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(markerLatLng)
                .title("Latitude :" + markerLatLng.latitude + " and Longitude:"+ markerLatLng.longitude)
                // .snippet("Description")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createDrawableFromView(this, marker))));

        final View mapView = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map).getView();
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(markerLatLng, 10));
    }
```

And this is my asyntask class:

```
private class DownloadImageFromUrl extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Create a progressdialog
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Map.this);
                // Set progressdialog title
                mProgressDialog.setTitle("Download Image Tutorial");
                // Set progressdialog message
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                // Show progressdialog
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... URL) {

                String imageURL = URL[0];

                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                try {
                    // Download Image from URL
                    InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imageURL).openStream();
                    // Decode Bitmap
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return bitmap;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                // Set the bitmap into ImageView
                imageFromUrl.setImageBitmap(result);
                // Close progressdialog
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should download all your data and only then try to show a map? 
Nice custom icon factory exists in [Android Maps Utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/demo/src/com/google/maps/android/utils/demo/IconGeneratorDemoActivity.java)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

1.Download Latest AndroidQuery jar from [here][1]:

2.Put this jar to your libs folder and right click on jar and Build Path -> Add to bulid path.

3.How to use see this example:

```
AQuery androidQuery = new AQuery(this);

androidQuery.ajax(url, Bitmap.class, 0, new AjaxCallback<Bitmap>() {
   @Override
   public void callback(String url, Bitmap object, AjaxStatus status) {
       super.callback(url, object, status);
       googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("yourtitle").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(object)).position(new LatLng(yourlatitude), Double.parseDouble(yourlongitude))));
   }
});
```